# What's the trampoline sound in some solo piano recordings?

Tags: piano, technique, recording

I listen to classical music while I study. I've noticed a couple songs that have a kind of springing, trampoline-like sound in them. What is that? Is it an artifact of a specific play style or some kind of percussive element?

Examples with Spotify Links:

- ["Prends soin de toi"](https://open.spotify.com/track/2Fh9R2pniRV3HgCjj61q9S?si=oNYQ1gYFSle3a1oaz4AOxA) by artist Falerina Paquet
- ["Rana ura, zlata ura"](https://open.spotify.com/track/2jDEufyL95jHPBuxOf5Azt?si=v4nCjpKSTFCcICZ_xJ6uIA) by artist Valbona Ceferin

Comment: These are copyrighted and I couldn't find any samples on YouTube, etc. Open to suggestions, though.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xryt-8XeLQU , its a different track, but it has the same noises as the others

Answer (score 2):

To me it sounds like the sustain pedal of the piano being pressed (the sounds usually appears at the beginning of a new chord). If that is the case, it is strangely loud. Because it is in recordings from both artists, its either an intentional choice to keep them (maybe even amplify them?) or maybe both recorded in the same studio with the same old piano.

On another note, and I might be wrong here / or overly pedantic, but these are often preferred to be called pieces (not songs). Also these are borderline classical music, maybe modern minimalism, but they follow rather the structure of pop compositions (chord progressions and repetition). Happy if anybody wants to correct me on this.

Comment: IMO not pedantic. Songs are sung... by a voice.

Comment: Could be an artistic choice, as in some recordings of cello or guitar for instance, the left hand action is very audible. 
Your hypothesis about the same piano in the same studio seems legit to me, as both have IMO the same sound